# Can I use environment variables in a .css file with Next.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, environment-variables, tailwind-css

I have a personal project with Next.js and Tailwind CSS, however in the globals.css file I have the following piece of code:

```
// styles/globals.css
@import url('https://use.typekit.net/...'); // I need to encapsulate this url in an environment variable
    
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
//...
```

Do you know if it is possible? Since so far I have understood the facility to use environment variables in JavaScript, but not in a separate file like a .css

Comment: What about importing the file above your `global.css` in `_app.js`? You should have access to your environment variables there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use environnement variable in my CSS using nextJs to specify base color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78200034/how-do-i-use-environnement-variable-in-my-css-using-nextjs-to-specify-base-color)